# WebSession ClassCastException

Tags: session, wicket, classcastexception, wicket-1.5

I've been trying to subclass Wicket's WebSession so I can implement a basic authentication system. I have followed the guidelines in the Wicket reference library. When I try the following in my WebPage, I get a ClassCastException:

```
((AppSession)Session.get()).setUid()
```

Here is the full error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession cannot be cast to com.example.webapp.AppSession
```

I've been searching the web for hours and tried everything I could. I would really appreciate some help. Also, please let me know if there is a better way of doing this. I'm really new to wicket.

Thank you.

**AppSession.java**

```
public final class AppSession extends WebSession {
    private Integer uid;

    public AppSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public final Integer getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public final void setUid(Integer uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public static AppSession get() {
        return (AppSession)Session.get();
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends WebApplication {
    public App() {
        super();
        new AnnotatedMountScanner().scanPackage("com.example.webapp").mount(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
        return new AppSession(request);     
    }

    @Override
    public Class getHomePage() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too have my own session class, descended from `WebSession`. I do a few things differently from you.

Add the `AppSession` method:

```
/**
 * Gets the session for the calling thread.
 * @return
 *   The session for the calling thread.
 */
public static AppSession get()
{
  return (AppSession)Session.get();
}
```

You might want to try

```
AppSession ssnSession = AppSession.get();
ssnSession.setUid(...);
```

instead of your one-line call.

Have you checked the packages of your (App)Session classes?

(I personally do not return `null` for your `App.getHomePage()`.)

Does any of this help?

Comment: Wouldn't that be an issue with multiple users and the lifespan of the AppSession?

Comment: @monksy No, because `AppSession.get()` returns the session of the user whose web request is being processed.

Comment: This is the correct answer, althought the one-liner call is not wrong. I use it all the time :)  MySession.get().getUsername() etc.